# Module Not Found Error on the Scripts/translate.js on running build command

Tags: reactjs, node.js, babeljs, babel-node

I updated react version to 16.8.0 `from 15.4.2, updated all the packages and dependencies.
When I try to do run build getting below error:

expert-care@0.0.1 build
babel-node scripts/translate.js

node :internal/modules/loader:1051
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '...................................................\scripts\translate.js
at Module._ resolve Filename (node: internal/modules/ /loader:1048:15)
at Module._ load (node: internal/modules/ /loader:901:27)
at Function. execute User Entry Point [as run Main] (node: internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at Object. (.............................\node_modules@babel\node\lib_babel-node.js:147:21)
at Module._ compile (node: internal/modules`/ /loader:1241:14) at Module._extensions..js (node: internal/modules/ /loader:1295:10) at Module. load (node: internal/modules/ /loader:1091:32) at Module._ load (node: internal/modules/ /loader:938:12) at Function. execute User Entry Point` [as run Main] (node: internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node : internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
require Stack: [`]
}

Node.js v20.9.0

Here is the babel config file

```
"presets": ["@babel/ preset",` "@babel/ preset-react"," @babel`/preset-es2015","@babel/preset-es2015-         

 loose","@babel/preset-stage-0","`@babel/poly fill"]
 "plugins": [
  "transform-object-assign",
  "transform-react-display-name"
   ],
  "environment": {
  "development": {
   "plugins": [
   "react-hot-loader/babel"
    ]
  }
}
```

How to fix this error?

How to resolve build run issue?

Comment: It is going to be hard for people to answer your question in its current state. Please include the content of your `build` script, and fix the formatting of the errors/json you have shared.

Also there seems to be random backticks (`) all over your post.